Safari remove pointer on video-elements (shadow dom)
i try to use a custom cursor for that i need to remove the default cursor from all elements. This is could do and it works (mostly) and i also added the websit media controls shadow-dom elements and set the cursor to none:
* {
    cursor: none !important;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls,
video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button,
video::-webkit-media-controls-panel,
video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button,
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline,
video::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display,
video::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display,
video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button,
video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider,
video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {
    cursor: none !important;
    &:hover, 
    &:focus {
        cursor: none !important;
    }
}

But now i have problem that firefox and safari still show my default curson when hover with my mouse over it. DO i nee to use different elements than i need to focus and remove the cursor there?
Thank you for your help!
